# Emscripten build with USE_ICU = 1 and Always failed with U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR after calling ubrk_open()

Tags: webassembly, emscripten, icu

We want to achieve a text break iterator based on ICU for our wasm project. However, when we call ubrk_open() to create an instance, it always failed with U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR.

```
bool TextBreakIteratorImpl::Init() {
  UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
  switch (break_type_) {
    case TextBreakIterator::TextBreakType::BREAK_NEWLINE: {
      iter_ = ubrk_open(UBRK_LINE, nullptr, nullptr, 0, &status);
      break;
    }
    case TextBreakIterator::TextBreakType::BREAK_WORD: {
      iter_ = ubrk_open(UBRK_WORD, nullptr, nullptr, 0, &status);
      break;
    }
  }

  if (U_FAILURE(status) || iter_ == nullptr) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently libicu requires a data files to be loaded: http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata.   Sadly there are no exmaples/tests of how you are expected to do that in emscripten as of now.   It seems there are several options but its not clear which one is possible/recommended here.  I opened bug: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/14754